# Downloading Source Code From Google Code using TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, google-code

I recently found a cool little project that I would like to download the source code of. Using the web interface on Google Code, I can browse through all of the files in the source code of the project.

Google gives me this:

```
# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://xnamugen.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xnamugen-read-only
```

So I tried to use TortiseSVN to download the source code, however it is asking me for a username and password. Why is this, and what is the password to access source code using a SVN client? I assume the author hasn't password protected the source or anything because you can still see it and download it using the web interface provided by Google.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to configure your proxy inside tortoise (if you have one) or it will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to password-protect checkouts in Google code. It also protects commits (duh), and files uploaded to the group's "Files" section using a "command line utility", as they state it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try not typing any login nor password ?

*(I don't have Tortoise SVN, but tryied with another client, not typing any login/password, and I have access to the repository)*

Answer (score 0):

Try using command line.I have faced the same problem previously.

Answer (score 0):

Checked out the source code, and it didn't asked for username/password. Maybe you should update your TortoiseSVN client?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using http, not https for the Google code url. If you use https, you're asked for a password.